# how to implement an asynch sub call in vb.net and c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Probably the most common and neeeded programming pattern of all is that where an asynch function is called and the calling function waits for its completion.

Psuedo Code:

```
do

  Execute TimeConsumingSub asynchronously

  Wait for TimeConsumingSub to complete for a maximum of 100 seconds

  if TimeConsumingSub has timed out
    do something
  else
    do something else
  end if

loop
```

What is the c#, vb.net equivalent of this pseudo code?

Comment: does `TimeConsumingSub` already exist? if so: what pattern does it use? is it `async`? does it return a `Task[<T>]`? is the a `[Begin|End]TimeConsumeSub` pair? or is it a synchronous method that you want to call *concurrently*?

Comment: Asking us to write your code for you is not acceptable on SO. While I do appreciate the effort in the pseudocode (and the intention is clear), you're still not asking about a problem with **existing** code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking us to write code for him.

Comment: TimeConsumingSub does not exist. I am asking what is the vb.net &/or c# language construct that is used to implement the supplied pseudocode. I suspect there is none which is a huge pity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code equivelent, built as small as possible:

```
Dim _TimeConsumingSubCompleted as Boolean = False 
'global variable to use, set to true at end of your subroutine.
            Do
            Await Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAny(TimeConsumingSub, Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100000))
            If _TimeConsumingSubCompleted Then
                'do something
            Else
                'Do something else
            End If
        Loop
```

This makes use of Task.WaitAny to run both your consuming sub and a delay next to each other, and finishes awaiting execution until either one is complete.

Comment: Thanks. It is a bit low level. What is _TimeConsumingSubCompleted? It is a pity there is not a specific language construct to implement such a common pattern.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: For this to work, we use Tasks. Tasks, await and async are all parts of what you want in the .NET framework.